# Function to reverse print

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

Yesterday I had to solve an exam exercise, which, unfortunately, I failed..
The exercise was to create a function in C with the following rules:

- Write a function that takes a string and displays the string in reverse
  order followed by the newline.
- Its prototype is constructed like this : char *ft_rev_print (char *str)
- It must return its argument
- Only allowed to use function 'write'(so no printf or others)

With that information I wrote :

```
int     ft_strlen(char *str) /*to count the length of the original string*/
{
    int     i;
    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
            i++;
    return (i);
}
char    *ft_rev_print (char *str)
{
    int     i;

    i = ft_strlen(str);
    while (i)
    {
            write (1, (str +1), 1);
            i--;
    }
    return (str);             /*returning its argument */
}

int     main(void)     /*IT HAD TO WORK WITH THIS MAIN, DID NOT WROTE THIS MYSELF!*/
{
    ft_rev_print("rainbow dash");
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

I tried for ages to get it to work, but failed.. So now I'm breaking my head over this. What did i do wrong ? What did i miss?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 'i = 0; while (i)'......

Comment: 'ft_strlen()' is not used, so why post it?

Comment: oopsie, mistake with recreating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters your teachers are not enough qualified. The functiuon should be declared at least like

```
char * ft_rev_print( const char *str );
                     ^^^^^
```

because the passed string is not changed within the function.

You forgot to call the function `ft_strlen`.

It seems you mean

```
i = ft_strlen( str );
```

As a result this loop

```
i = 0;
while (i)
{
    //...
}
```

is never executed because initially `i` is equal to `0` and the condition of the loop at once evaluates to false.

Also in this call

```
write (1, (str +1), 1);
          ^^^^^^^^
```

you are always trying to output the second symbol of the string.

Also the output of the new line character `'\n'` should be within the function according to its description.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below (instead of the non-standard function `write` I will use the function `putchar` but you can substitute it for `write` yourself)

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * ft_rev_print( const char *str )
{
    const char *p = str;
    
    while ( *p ) ++p;
    
    while ( p != str ) putchar( *--p );  // substitute the call of putchar for write( 1, *--p, 1 )
    
    putchar( '\n' );  // substitute the call of putchar for write( 1, "\n", 1 )
    
    return ( char * )str;
}

int main(void) 
{
    ft_rev_print( "rainbow dash" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hsad wobniar
```

Comment: Awesome explanation ! thanks! To be fair they actually said the string cannot be modifiable, but i forgot that one. so i needed to compare the str with a constant char it would seem. 
Really helpful !

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop is wrong, you start with i=0 and iterate while it's not zero, so no iterations will be done.

What you should do is:

- initialize i so that it is the index of the last character
- loop as long as it's a valid index
- print the i-th character, not always the second (at index one)

```
char *ft_rev_print (char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = ft_strlen(str) - 1; // <-- Initialize i to be the index of the last character
    while (i >= 0) // <-- Loop as long as it's valid
    {
        write (1, (str+i), 1); // <-- Print the i-th character
        i--;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! cannot believe i missed that ... -_- this sucks... thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have tried your question and there is a small point I would like to add,In your question you have written the length of your string and also the part below in your code:

```
  write (1, (str +1), 1);
```

was not correct so I corrected it and in that basically we are adding the back of previous characters like this and error was in a while loop condition:

write (1,(str+i),1);

You can full prototype here:

```
char    *ft_rev_print (char *str)
{
    int     i;
     i = ft_strlen(str);//returning the length of string
     while (i>=0)
     {
            write (1,(str+i),1);
            i--;
     }
    return (str);             /*returning its argument */
}
```